# Having a list of sounds in a UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIPickerView, and I have 10 sounds. I want to implement the 10 sounds into a UIPickerView. So once the user scrolls through the picker view, each sound plays.
I'm pretty new to obj c, so bear with me please.

Here is the current code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TesttimeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pickLabel;

}

@end


#import "TesttimeViewController.h"

@implementation TesttimeViewController

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list count];
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Now Playing: %@", [list objectAtIndex:row]];
                        pickLabel.text = string;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"100"];
    [list addObject:@"2100"];
    [list addObject:@"1300"];
    [list addObject:@"1400"];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

All this does is select the text then shows in a uilabel which text has been selected in the uipickerview.

Thanks